# dotnet core react redux typescript, how to connect component that has ownProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, .net-core

I have a Layout component that looks like this.

```
export interface LayoutProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps, {}> {

}

export const routes  = <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route exact path='/test' component={test} />
</Layout>;
```

I want to connect Layout to redux but I haven't been able to do it, I always get type errors and I'm too novice at javascript to understand how to use the typescript redux connect function to do what I want to do.

I tried this (among many other things)

```
export interface Props extends UserContext.State, LayoutProps { }
```

This is how dotnet core react redux template uses connect, I added the ownProps part.

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.userContext,
    UserContext.actionCreators,
    (ownProps: Props) => ownProps.children
)(Layout) as typeof Layout;
```

The typescript error I get on my Layout component where I use it to inject routes.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error TS2322  (TS) Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to
>   type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
>   Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Re...'.   Type '{ children:
>   Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
>       Property 'user' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; }'.    xxxxxxxx.ClientPortal.Web.Public (tsconfig
>   project)  D:\xxxxxxxx\TFS
>   Projects\xxxxxxxx.Internal\Source\DEV\xxxxxxxx.Internal\xxxxxxxx.ClientPortal.Web.Public\ClientApp\routes.tsx 8   Active

Typescript redux is so complicated for a beginner, plain javascript redux is far easier, can someone help me with a solution to make Layout a connected component while maintaining its ability to have children?

Or you can direct me to very good documentation on typescript redux that doesn't assume I already know 90% of it.

**EDIT**

This following works, kind of...

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState, ownProps: LayoutProps) => ({
    email: state.userContext.user.email,
    children: ownProps.children,
});
```

I have to make props 'any' here because I don't have a single type, the props are a composition of multiple types, not sure how to do this...

```
class Layout extends React.Component<any, {}> {
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout);
```

This doesn't throw any errors except that routing is broken now, the pages do not change when I navigate to these routes, it does change when I write the url myself.

Comment: I used
`export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  otherFunc
)(Screen)`

Comment: @patko Have you solved it? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I don't get an error if i do it like below, but my routes don't work either, haven't had any time to look more into this but maybe its a start for you.

export interface LayoutProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState, ownProps: LayoutProps) => ({
    email: state.userContext.user.email,
    children: ownProps.children,
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout);